# How to permanently enable/disable lens

Tags: unity-dash, lenses, recoll

I've installed this old PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:recoll-backports/recoll-1.15-on
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install recoll unity-scope-recoll
```

to get recoll search results integrated into Unity dash.

Some months ago, I've installed the lens package only from that PPA. Although theoretically unsupported, but works with the Unity dash in 16.04.

The problem is that it's either enabled or disabled by default. I have to click filter results, and tick the recoll scope off or on.

Currently, recoll search is on by default, but the results supplants the original Unity file search powered by Zeitgeist. Because it seems that the two results can't be integrated want I want the Recoll results soft-disabled so that the Zeitgeist results show by default (because I access a lot of regular files that way) and want the recoll scope only activate when I type `recoll:` in the dash search.

How can I make this way? It seems that if I soft-disable recoll scope in the filter results, next time I open the dash search it's on again, so I have to disable it, to get the Zeitgeist results.

Can anybody help about this? This is the same with any other custom enabled/disabled lens.

Thanks in advance!